# How do partial derivatives of a function differ under change of variable?

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

I have a function $f$ that can be expressed either as $f(x, t)$ or $f(g, t)$, where $g = g(x, t)$ and $x = x(t)$. What are the partial derivatives of each with respect to $t$? I was thinking it was this:

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial t} f(x, t) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}
$$

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial t} f(g, t) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial g} \frac{\partial g}{\partial t}
$$

But then some other equations I am working with suggest that

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial t} f(x, t) - \frac{\partial}{\partial t} f(g, t) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial g} \frac{\partial g}{\partial t}
$$

Whereas the previous equations obviously imply

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial t} f(x, t) - \frac{\partial}{\partial t} f(g, t) = -\frac{\partial f}{\partial g} \frac{\partial g}{\partial t}
$$

So I am doubting that I have the partial derivatives at the top correct.

Comment: When you "express" your function $f$ in different ways you define different functions. Calling all of these functions $f$ may seem suitable to whatever problem you're working on, where "$f$" is a quantity you need for some further step, but it makes very ambiguous notation. Also, it looks like in some places you are taking a total derivative rather than a partial derivative. Are you sure these are **all** partial derivatives?

Comment: @DavidK I am sure in the sense that, in my applied context, these are partial derivatives appearing in Ito's Lemma. However, it seems to me that people take a lot of liberties in their definition of the partial differentiation operator when manipulating the Lemma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First part:** Here we start with the first part and consider
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dt}f(x,t)\qquad x=x(t)\tag{1}
\end{align*}
in some detail. It is convenient to use the somewhat more general setting
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dt}f(x,y)\qquad x&=x(t)\\
y&=y(t)\tag{2}
\end{align*}
to better see what's going on. The case (1) is a special case of (2) with $y(t)=t$.

> We obtain from (2) applying the *[chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule)*
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\frac{d}{dt}}&\color{blue}{f\left(x(t),y(t)\right)}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=f_x\left(x(t),y(t)\right)x^{\prime}(t)+f_y\left(x(t),y(t)\right)y^{\prime}(t)}\tag{3}
> \end{align*}
> or more compactly written
> \begin{align*}
> \frac{d}{dt}f=f_xx^{\prime}+f_yy^{\prime}
> \end{align*}

With $y=y(t)=t$ the expression (3) boils down to
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\frac{d}{dt}f\left(x(t),t\right)
=f_x\left(x(t),t\right)x^{\prime}(t)+f_y\left(x(t),t\right)}
\end{align*}

**Example:** We calculate a small example in two different ways
\begin{align*}
f(x,y)=x^2y^3+\sin y\qquad x(t)&=2t^2+1\\
y(t)&=t
\end{align*}

On the one hand we obtain according to (3)
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\frac{d}{dt}}&\color{blue}{f\left(x(t),y(t)\right)}\\
&=\frac{d}{dt}\left(x^2(t)y^3(t)+\sin\left(y(t)\right)\right)\\
&=2x(t)y^3(t)x^{\prime}(t)+\left(3x^2(t)y^2(t)+\cos(y(t))\right)y^{\prime}(t)\\
&=2\left(2t^2+1\right)t^3\left(4t\right)+3\left(2t^2+1\right)^2t^2+\cos(t)\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=28t^6+20t^4+3t^2+\cos(t)}\tag{4}
\end{align*}

On the other hand we get
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\frac{d}{dt}}&\color{blue}{f\left(x(t),y(t)\right)}\\
&=\frac{d}{dt}\left(\left(2t^2+1\right)^2t^3+\sin(t)\right)\\
&=\frac{d}{dt}\left(4t^7+4t^5+t^3+\sin (t)\right)\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=28t^6+20t^4+3t^2+\cos(t)}
\end{align*}
in accordance with (4).

**Second part:** OP wants also to calculate
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dt}f(g,t)\qquad g=g\left(x(t),t\right)
\end{align*}
Again, it's more convenient to consider a slightly more general setting, namely
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dt}f(g,h)\qquad g&=g\left(x(t),y(t)\right)\\
h&=h(t)
\end{align*}

Here I indicate the derivation using the compact notation only. The details follow the lines of the example above.

> We obtain applying the chain rule twice
> \begin{align*}
> \frac{d}{dt}f\left(g\left(x(t),y(t)\right),h(t)\right)
> &=f_g g^{\prime}+f_h h^{\prime}\\
> &=f_g\left(g_x x^{\prime}+g_y y^{\prime}\right)+f_h h^{\prime}
> \end{align*}

Comment: You are giving me the total derivative. How would the answer change if you replace $d/dt$ with $\partial/\partial t$ on the left hand side of the equation?

Comment: @ben: Here we have the special case that $f$ is a function of one independent variable $t$. There is no reason to use the partial differential operator $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}$. The usage of the differential operator $\frac{d}{dt}$ is adequate.

Comment: @ben: Many thanks for accepting my answer and granting the bounty. :-)